# laravel 5 create session file works on local but not on live

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My application works in local smoothly,but in online live server it always create a new session file in **storage/framework/sessions** . It shows always token mismatch. I can't find out where is my fault? Actually it works fine in my local server.

**My Routes are:**

```
Route::get('/', ['as'=>'dashboardRoute','uses'=>'DashboardController@index']);
//imports
Route::get('import/emails', ['as' => 'importEmailFormRoute', 'uses' => 'ImportController@getEmailImport']);
Route::post('import/emails', ['as' => 'importEmailPostRoute', 'uses' => 'ImportController@postEmailImport']);
Route::get('import/contacts', ['as' => 'importContactFormRoute', 'uses' => 'ImportController@getContactImport']);
Route::post('import/contacts', ['as' => 'importContactPostRoute', 'uses' => 'ImportController@postContactImport']);
//end imports
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@profile');
Route::post('user/profile', 'UserController@profileUpdate');

Route::resource('email', 'EmailController');
Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactController');
Route::resource('email-group', 'EmailGroupController');
Route::resource('contact-groups', 'ContactGroupController');
Route::resource('group-data', 'GroupDataController');
Route::resource('contact-group-datas', 'ContactGroupDataController');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
Route::resource('mail-log', 'EmailLogController');
Route::resource('sms-log', 'SmsLogController');

Route::get('send-form', 'SendMailController@sendEmailForm');
Route::get('group-mail-form', 'SendMailController@groupMailForm');
Route::post('send', 'SendMailController@sendMail');
Route::post('send-to-group', 'SendMailController@sendMailToGroup');


Route::get('sms/custom-send', ['as' => 'sendCustomSmsFormRoute', 'uses' => 'SmsController@getSendCustomSms']);
Route::post('sms/custom-send', ['as' => 'sendCustomSmsPostRoute', 'uses' => 'SmsController@postSendCustomSms']);

Route::get('sms/send-to-group', ['as' => 'sendGroupSmsFormRoute', 'uses' => 'SmsController@getSendGroupSms']);
Route::post('sms/send-to-group', ['as' => 'sendGroupSmsPostRoute', 'uses' => 'SmsController@postSendGroupSms']);

// api
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('email', ['as' => 'tagEmailListRoute', 'uses' => 'ApiController@tagEmailList']);
    Route::get('contact', ['as' => 'tagContactListRoute', 'uses' => 'ApiController@getTagContactList']);

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'data-table'], function () {
        Route::get('emails', ['as' => 'emailListDataTableRoute', 'uses' => 'ApiController@emailListDataTable']);
    });
});
//end api

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

My session config:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Comment: can you give more details? what error you get? when you get the error? in all routes? is specific one?

Comment: All of my route with auth middleware. when i browse my root path of site it redirect me to auth/login path showing on screen redirecting.... If i provide login details it shows token mismatch

Comment: Can you share your `login.blade.php`?

Comment: Everything is okay in my localhost,problem is in live server. In login.blade.php clrf token helper is exist. @smartrahat

Comment: I am having this problem too. But this occurs when I browse login page and give my username & password after long time (approx 3/4 hours). May be there are some `_token` expire issues.